# How to replace character in HTML string with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, draftjs

I'm using `sanitize-html` to clean pasted text for `draftJS` editor.

Lets say result might be text string like this

`<h1 class="title">
  President said "<b>Give this man a money</b>" and i agree
</h1`

Now i need to replace `"` with `«` or `»` depends on conditions. 
How should i do that. I tried to figure out if i can do it with `draftJS` `ContentBlock` methods, but it seems way too complicated. So i think it is easier to modify html string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two regular expressions I guess:

```js
    var inputString = `<h1 class="title">
      President said "<b>Give this man a money</b>" and i agree
    </h1>`
      , startingQuoteRE = / "/g
      , endingQuoteRE = /" /g
      , outputString = ''
      ;
    outputString = inputString.replace(startingQuoteRE, " «");
    outputString = outputString.replace(endingQuoteRE, "» ");
    // Or by chaining .replace
    // outputString = inputString.replace(startingQuoteRE, " «").replace(endingQuoteRE, "» ");
    console.log(outputString);
```

Comment: Wasn't there something about not parsing HTML with RegEx?

Comment: @Eldy yes, it's not recommended to parse HTML using RegEx. But here we are not parsing any HTML, just doing some strings replacements.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `replaceAll` function. Because `replace` function will replace the only first occurrence.

   ```
   String.prototype.replaceAll = function(string, replace) {
   return this.split(string).join(replace);
   };
   ```
2. Call the function like this.

   ```
   var str = '<h1 class="title">\
   President said "<b>Give this man a money</b>" and i agree\
   </h1>';
   var result = str.replaceAll('"','\'');
   console.log(result);
   ```